# Global Keylogger in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, keylogger

I want to make a **Keylogger** happen in **Java Swing**. I could manage to make a simple keylogger that catches Keystrokes and writes them to a logfile, when the **focus** is on the Swing Window. Since the **focus** has to be on the window, is it possible to make an **invisible JFrame**, that is **always on top**?
Something like this:

```
public class Logger extends JFrame implements KeyListener


logger.setVisible(false);
logger.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: I’m having trouble picturing an ethical reason for doing this.  Not that it’s possible in Java, regardless.

Comment: An ethical reason is for example to make global hotkeys for your application. Something like any music programs global hotkey to start or pause the track.
But in fact I m just curious about malware and how easy it is to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want a key logger that record keystroke even the focus is not on Java Swing window, right? 
Java itself cannot do this, but Java Native Interface (JNI) can. You could Google "Java System Hook" and download the JAR from Github. (https://github.com/kristian/system-hook/releases) In one word, it keeps recording your keyboard as long as the program runs, regardless of which window you are focusing on.

The way I use it: I wrote a program that keep running while I play games and it can print out whatever key I press in the game.

Comment: Ty sir. Just looked into it. For this case it would make more sense to make the whole thing in C++ then.